# Can't add a ModuleInfo object to ArrayList<? extends ModuleInfo>

Tags: java, generics, netbeans

I'm not sure if I am using generics correctly, but basically I created an `Arraylist<? extends ModuleInfo> moduleList` and `ModuleInfo m` objects, and tried to call `moduleList.add(m)`. However it won't compile and I am getting an error message that seems a bit cryptic to me. The error message and code are below. Anyone else know what is wrong?

```
void load() {
    ArrayList<? extends ModuleInfo> moduleList = new ArrayList();
    Iterator<? extends ModuleInfo> iter_m;
    ModuleInfo m;

    //get modules that depend on this module
    //retrieve list of all modules and iterate trough each one
    iter_m = Lookup.getDefault().lookupAll(ModuleInfo.class).iterator();
    while(iter_m.hasNext()) {
        m = iter_m.next();
        //loop through modules dependencies and check for a dependency on this module
        for(Dependency d : m.getDependencies()) {
            //if found, the module to the list
            if(d.getName().equals(GmailAuthManager.class.getPackage().getName())) {
                moduleList.add(m);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error is a follows:

```
error: no suitable method found for add(ModuleInfo)
                    moduleList.add(m);
    method ArrayList.add(int,CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual argument ModuleInfo cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends ModuleInfo from capture of ? extends ModuleInfo
```

Comment: You declare moduleList to be of type `ArrayList<? extends ModuleInfo>` but when you construct the new ArrayList, there's no type.  Shouldn't it be `new ArrayList<? extends ModuleInfo>();`

Comment: I changed the declaration to `ArrayList<ModuleInfo>` and it works fine. I was confused and thought it needed to be that way because the Collection that gets returned from the Lookup object is `Collection<? extends ModuleInfo>`.

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you create an arraylist as: -

```
List<? extends Animal> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

Now that list reference can point to an `ArrayList<Dog>` or an `ArrayList<Cat>` or whatever. So, when you try to add an `Animal` reference to that list, compiler is not sure that, that reference is actually pointing the same `implementation` that is used in actual Concrete type of `ArrayList`.

For e.g.: - You might add an `Animal` reference pointing to `Cat` into the above ArrayList, which is a disaster. That's why Compiler does not allow it.

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
list.add(cat);  // OOps.. You just put a Cat in a list of Dog
```

You can rather just create a `List<Animal>`, and you can add any subtype to it: -

```
List<Animal> newList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
newList.add(new Cat());  // Ok. Can add a `Cat` to an `Animal` list.
```

The above code works because, a `List<Animal>` reference can only point to an `ArrayList<Animal>`.

---

So, in your example, you can use: -

```
List<ModuleInfo> list = new ArrayList<ModuloInfo>();
```

As a side note, you should always program to `interface` rather than `implementation`. So, always have your reference types of `interface`, in this case `List` rather than `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue use:

```
ArrayList<ModuleInfo> moduleList = new ArrayList<ModuleInfo>();
```

This will restrict your list to ModuleInfo instances as well as their subclasses.