# Wildcard, how it works?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Code:

```
List<? extends Integer> ints= new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(3);//error
```

I still dont understand how it works. **Question:**

What does mean `CAP#1`? Is it a reference type? I think, no, because CAP#1 doesnt inherited from `Object`. We can write `ints.add(null);//OK` and we havent compile time error. But we cant write `null instanceof CAP#1;//compile-time error`. Why we cant instanciate `CAP#1`:

```
CAP#1 c= new CAP#1();
```

From what `CAP#1` appears?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't add a ModuleInfo object to ArrayList<? extends ModuleInfo>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499928/cant-add-a-moduleinfo-object-to-arraylist-extends-moduleinfo)

Comment: @Rohit Jain I have the following question: Does compiler know that for  method `boolean add(? extends Integer)` argument's type `? extends Integer` defined by `CAP#1` where CAP#1 in this case- a special type, who may has only one instance- `null`? Does this question correct? If correct, please answer.

Answer (score 5):

`CAP#1` is the compiler's name for the implicit type variable represented by the '`?`'.  There is no such named type, but the compiler needs to create a placeholder for the type in order to complete its work.  The name stands for "capture".

It helps to mentally rewrite a type like `G<? extends T>` to `∃CAP#1 extends T: G< CAP#1 >`.

You can't add anything to a list with a wildcard extends type, because you don't know what that wildcard stands for.  Just like you can't add a `Snake` to a `List< Mammal >`, you can't add it to a `List< ? extends Animal >` because that `?` might turn out to represent `Mammal`.

You can, however, always add `null` in this situation because `null` is effectively a member of every reference type, which necessarily includes whatever the `?` could possibly represent.

I've often wondered why Java doesn't treat `List< ? extends F >` for some final type `F` the same as `List< F >`.  Maybe it's because `F` could itself be a generic wildcard type, which would mean it would still have arbitrarily many subtypes.

Aside from Angelika Langer's famous FAQ about Java generics, I've been compiling [some things](http://jazzjuice.blogspot.com/2012/01/uses-of-wildcard-types-in-java.html) about them in my own list.

Comment: _CAP#1 is the compiler's name for the implicit type variable represented by the '?'_ What does mean implicit type? Does compiler know that for all implicit type we have only one instance of this? It's `null`. I think, it is not true. Because if we consider wildcard with `super` we also have implicit type: `List<? super Integer> ints= new ArrayList<Integer>(); ints.add("dsd");//Compile error ints.add(4);//ok`

Comment: You should always read a wildcard type like `G<? extends T>` as &exists; `S extends T: G< S >`.  Regarding the behavior of the compiler w.r.t. super, look up "PECS" (producer extends, consumer super).

Comment: `∃CAP#`n `extends T: G< CAP#`n `>`

Answer (score 2):

means Number or an unknown a sub class. If you obtain such a value it will be a Number, but you cannot give a value of this type because you don't know which is valid.

for more follow this answer:
[What is the difference between List<Number> and List<? extends Number>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216326/what-is-the-difference-between-listnumber-and-list-extends-number)