# implicit type and wildcard

Tags: java, wildcard, implicit

In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311808/wildcard-how-it-works) i faced with implict types.

**Question 1.** What's **strong** defenition of implicit type in Java or it's non-formal concept? Can i define implicit type manually? Is it true that all of implicit type is the same? What's the implicit type for compiler?

The following code example:

```
List<? extends Number> nums= new ArrayList<Integer>();
nums.add(3);//error
```

I know that we can assign to `nums` reference to `ArrayList<Double>`.

**Question 2.** In this context `? extends Number` is implicit type, defined by `CAP#1`. Is it true that compiler does know that only `null` is instance of this implicit type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper term is *capture of wildcard*. Compiler internally converts the *wildcard instantiation* of a generic type to the *capture of the wildcard*. The capture represents the particular unknown type of the type argument. This particular unknown type is, of course, a member of the type family that the wildcard denotes.

Note that, since there can be many different types that can be represented by wildcard instantiation, we say that wildcards represent a family of different instantiation of a parameterized types.

> Can i define implicit type manually?

Anonymous type variable? No. That is created by compiler internally. You can say that, you are instructing the compiler to create an anonymous type argument which will replace the wildcards used.

> Is it true that all of implicit type is the same?

No. If you use say `List<? extends Number>` twice as different types, they both will generate different anonymous types, viz, `CAP#1 extends Number` and `CAP#2 extends Number`.

> What's the implicit type for compiler?

I don't understand these questions.

> Is it true that compiler does know that only `null` is instance of this implicit type?

The reason why adding `null` works is due to the fact that, `null` is a valid value for any kind of reference. So, whatever the actual type argument the wildcard represent, would happily accept the value `null`.

Comment: _I don't understand these questions_ I thinked, that we can define implicit type in the code. You told, that implicit type is creating by compiler internally. Hence this questions is nonsence.

Comment: _Anonymous type argument?_ Can you post a reference to official docs about anonymous type argument?

Comment: @St.Antario It's not in the official doc. The term is used for the capture of wildcards in this tutorial - http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ501

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put anything into a type declared with an extends wildcard **except** for the value `null`, **which belongs to every reference type**

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<? extends Number> nums = ints;
nums.add(null); // ok
assert nums.toString().equals("[1,2,3,null]");
```

In general, if a structure contains elements with a type of the form `? extends E`, we **can get
elements out of the structure**, but we **cannot** put elements into the structure (except `null`). To put
elements into the structure we need `super` wildcard:

```
    List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<Number>();
    nums.add(2);
    nums.add(3.14);

    List<? super Integer> ints = nums;

    ints.add(3); 
    ints.add(null);
```

Result: `[2, 3.14, null]`